# Is it possible to test google In-app Billing Version used?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I received notice from google saying my app uses In-app Billing Version 2 which will be dropped next year. I use Adobe AIR to develop my app and use a third party ANE for the In-app Billing function. The ANE developer assured me it is using In-app Billing Version 3. I also agree because I am making consume item calls which doesn't exist in In-app Billing Version 2.
But why does google think I am using In-app Billing Version 2? Is there a way to test/find out for sure?

Comment: did you find an answer, because I've got the same mail and I am using version 3?

Comment: I have not. I didn't find out a way to contact google about it either. I was going to hide my head in the sand and wait for the day to come and see. Good thing Android app updates don't have to wait weeks to be approved. Are you also using Adobe AIR ANE?

Comment: No, I don't use Adobe.AIR, but in the email I've got from Google there was an link to contact form where I can ask question. I wrote to them and they checked that my app didn't have any transactions for last 3 months with version 2 so I am not sure why I got this email.

Comment: Is is possible to point me to the form so I can ask them to check also? Thank you.

Comment: This link is generated for every developer, but I think you can try here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/2857301?hl=en

Comment: I submitted my question to google too and got reply quickly saying my app didn't generate any revenue from In-App billing version 2 in the last 3 months. So I guess the email was a mistake. Hopefully.

Comment: So like in my situation. That's good.